# How to increase the evaluation speed of this numerical integral?

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration

I have a three dimensional integration, which takes about 30s using `LocalAdaptive` and `"GaussKronrodRule"`. Using `GlobalAdaptive` and other rules will take more time. I have tried many different combinations of integration strategies, it seems that `Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}` is the fastest or some others will report error. I am wonder how to make this integration excute faster, the speed is very important to me. Below is the integration code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
k = Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2 + kz^2]; 
k0 = 1/100;  \[CapitalDelta]k = k0/10;  t0 = -1000;   v = 1;  z0 = 
 v t0;   kInfinity = 10 \[CapitalDelta]k; 


psi[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
  1/(2 Pi Sqrt[Pi] \[CapitalDelta]k)^(3/2)  NIntegrate[
    Exp[-kx^2/(2 \[CapitalDelta]k^2)] Exp[-ky^2/(2 \
\[CapitalDelta]k^2)] Exp[-(kz - k0)^2/(2 \[CapitalDelta]k^2)] Exp[
      I kx x] Exp[I ky y] Exp[
      I kz (z - z0)] Exp[-I k v (t - t0)] {Sqrt[(1 + kz/k)/
        2], (kx + I ky)/Sqrt[2 (k^2 + k kz)]}, {kx, -kInfinity, 
     kInfinity}, {ky, -kInfinity, kInfinity}, {kz, -kInfinity + k0, 
     kInfinity + k0}, 
    Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}];
```

Excuting using:

```
psi[0.01, 0.01, z0/2, t0/2] // Timing
```

Comment: I get five times faster result using the default options of `NIntegrate`. What speed-up are you looking for? (5 times, 100 times.) In what ranges of the parameters?

Comment: @AntonAntonov If it is possible, less 1s is acceptable, because later on I need to integrate w.r.t `x, y, z`. Note that the defaut option returns the result is not accurate, because I have an analytical expression. The result returned by my code is close to that expression.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the discrepancies in the integral estimates. Thanks.

Comment: I think it is better to separate your integral into two integrals -- you function `psi` calls `NIntegrate` with a vector of two elements. By separating into two integrals you can investigate and optimize the computations better. If I use the first term only, `Sqrt[(1 + kz/k)/2]`, `NIntegrate` finishes in less than a second. With the second term I can get some speed-up using certain options values...

Comment: can you post it? seperate is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did manage to get a 6-7 times speed up by separating the definition of `psi` into two integrals and experimenting with the option values. (I am not sure how significant the speed-up is... OP mentioned in the comments that 1 second is the goal.)

Here are the two new functions:

```
Clear[psi1]
psi1[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  1/(2 Pi Sqrt[Pi] \[CapitalDelta]k)^(3/2) NIntegrate[
    Exp[-kx^2/(2 \[CapitalDelta]k^2)] Exp[-ky^2/(2 \
\[CapitalDelta]k^2)] Exp[-(kz - k0)^2/(2 \[CapitalDelta]k^2)] Exp[
      I kx x] Exp[I ky y] Exp[
      I kz (z - z0)] Exp[-I k v (t - t0)] (Sqrt[(1 + kz/k)/
        2]), {kx, -kInfinity, kInfinity}, {ky, -kInfinity, 
     kInfinity}, {kz, -kInfinity + k0, kInfinity + k0}, opts];

Clear[psi2]
psi2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  1/(2 Pi Sqrt[Pi] \[CapitalDelta]k)^(3/2) NIntegrate[
    Exp[-kx^2/(2 \[CapitalDelta]k^2)] Exp[-ky^2/(2 \
\[CapitalDelta]k^2)] Exp[-(kz - k0)^2/(2 \[CapitalDelta]k^2)] Exp[
      I kx x] Exp[I ky y] Exp[
      I kz (z - z0)] Exp[-I k v (t - t0)] ((kx + I ky)/
       Sqrt[2 (k^2 + k kz)]), {kx, -kInfinity, 
     kInfinity}, {ky, -kInfinity, kInfinity}, {kz, -kInfinity + k0, 
     kInfinity + k0}, opts];
```

The functions are almost identical except for the terms coming from the vector `{Sqrt[(1 + kz/k)/2], (kx + I ky)/Sqrt[2 (k^2 + k kz)]}` in the original definition of `psi`.

Some computational results and timings follow. (Note that I have posted results with two different precision goals 5 and 6. With precision goal 3 the computations are even faster, and the obtained results reach the precision goal 6.)

#### Fastest computations adhering to communication with OP

```
In[127]:= psi1[1/100, 1/100, z0/2, t0/2, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive"}, 
  MinRecursion -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 3] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[127]= {0.070369, 0.0000133329 - 6.65116*10^-7 I}

In[126]:= psi2[1/100, 1/100, z0/2, t0/2, 
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 3] // Timing

Out[126]= {0.729304, -5.95563*10^-12 + 7.27904*10^-12 I}
```

#### PrecisionGoal->5

```
In[111]:= 
psi1[1/100, 1/100, z0/2, t0/2, 
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[111]= {0.787942, 0.0000133343 - 6.65033*10^-7 I}


In[112]:= 
psi2[1/100, 1/100, z0/2, t0/2, 
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 5] // Timing

Out[112]= {3.16929, -5.95563*10^-12 + 7.27904*10^-12 I}
```

#### PrecisionGoal->6

```
In[109]:= 
psi1[1/100, 1/100, z0/2, t0/2, 
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", 
    Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"}, PrecisionGoal -> 6] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[109]= {1.2058, 0.0000133343 - 6.65033*10^-7 I}


In[110]:= 
psi2[1/100, 1/100, z0/2, t0/2, 
  Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 6] // Timing

Out[110]= {7.79748, -5.95563*10^-12 + 7.27904*10^-12 I}
```

Comment: Is parallel possible for this problem? I have a multi core machine...

Comment: I do not think parallelization would help much in this case. What kind of precision and accuracy goals are you looking for?

Comment: I must stress tho that cubature is in general more difficult to do than quadrature ("curse of dimensionality"). Here, the OP is lucky that some speed-ups were possible. Now that I think about it: what if one uses an actual multidimensional rule like Genz-Malik (`"MultidimensionalRule"`) instead of taking a Cartesian product of one-dimensional rules?

Comment: @AntonAntonov accuracy goal about 3 is fine.

Comment: @buzhidao, any reason why you're not considering (quasi-)Monte Carlo, if you do not need so much accuracy anyway?

Comment: @J.M. montecaro returns the wrong results

Comment: Well sure @buzhidao, the default settings are usually not the most suitable, so you need to adjust them. Did you already look at [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#65285686)?

Comment: @J.M. maybe i should try to tune the options

Comment: @J.M. I mean PrecisionGoal actually.

Comment: @J.M. Using `MultidimensionalRule` the integrals get underestimated, but with higher `MinRecursion` the results are fine. And yes, for the first integral `psi1` I get the results 2 times faster. For `psi2` that rule is not working well -- I get "NIntegrate::eincr" messages.

Comment: @buzhidao See my update -- it seems I was able to produce the integral estimates in less than a second on my machine. Hopefully you'll get similar precision and speed for other parameters.